# How many unit vectors are perpendicular to $\langle 0,0,1\rangle$?

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

Am I correct that there would be infinitely many?
Let, $\vec{x} =  \langle x,y,z\rangle$ such that $\vec{x}$ is perpendicular to $\langle 0,0,1 \rangle$. So we have that,
$$\vec{x} ~ \cdot \langle 0,0,1\rangle  ~ =  0 \implies z = 0.$$
We also have to satisfy:
$$x^2+y^2 + z^2 = 1.$$
So then we have that,
$$x^2 + y^2 = 1.$$
The previous equation has infinitely many solutions, so then we obtain that the set
$$S = \{\langle x,y,0\rangle: x^2 + y^2 = 1  \}.$$
Generates all unit vectors perpendicular to $\langle 0,0,1\rangle$, and $|S| = \infty.$

Is my reasoning correct? Thanks.

Comment: A wheel at the end of an axle.

Comment: @Randall, I'm not sure I understand. Ok, I see now because the vectors "map" out a wheel and thats why they are infinitely many?

Comment: You are correct (in your post, too).  Note that $S$ is a circle, nicely.